# UI needs improvement when close vote has expired

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, close-dialog

The question is here - [Get caret XY coordinates in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082921/get-caret-xy-coordinates-in-text-area). It's an exact duplicate of [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709/how-do-i-get-the-x-y-pixel-coordinates-of-the-caret-in-text-boxes).

Apparently I voted to close it, but I don't see any number of votes in parentheses next to the "close" link, and I can't seem to be able to take any action on its closing (e.g. to retract my vote, or change the reason).

[image]

**UPDATE**: I understand that my close vote has expired, but

1. The UI should indicate that
2. The close reason I chose should be indicated as well. Right now it looks like a form that's missing a checkbox next to one of the options. On the other hand, why would it present multiple options to begin with, if I can't do anything about it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is that your closevote has expired because there where not enough votes to close the question.

Comment: It's an exact duplicate, yet not close. Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: It is now on meta, so if it has to be closed, it will be closed.

Comment: Note that even if you could have retracted your close vote, you would not be able to cast a new vote.

Comment: I can see modifying it to be clearer as per #1, but indicating which reason you actually chose requires adding an additional display element somewhere. Mixing it into the other numbers would be confusing. (PS it shows the options without boxes so you can still view the counts.)